# How to install latest version of nginx on raspbian?

Tags: linux, nginx, server, raspberry-pi, debian

What to specify in source.list? because when I write

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ jessie nginx
```

appears error:

```
Unable to find expected entry '' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to install the **last version of nginx on raspbian stretch**, by using the repo of **buster** the **next version** of raspbian.

Only three commands are needed:

```
# Add the url to apt source list
echo "deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10-buster.list
# Set preferences to give more priority to stretch
printf "Package: *\nPin: release n=stretch\nPin-Priority: 900\n\nPackage: *\nPin: release n=buster\nPin-Priority: 750" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/10-buster
# Update and install: -t is used to target a release and -yqq to confirm and reduce output  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -t buster nginx -yqq
```

At the time of writing, the [last stable version is 1.14.1](https://nginx.org/en/download.html). 
The same pointed out by `sudo apt-get install -t buster -s nginx`

Source: https://getgrav.org/blog/raspberrypi-nginx-php7-dev

Comment: Following these directions seems to have updated me from 1.10.3 which was from January 2017 up to 1.14.2 which is from December 2018... still 2.5 years old...  looks like the known security issues list is about half as long... but is there some way I can jump to 1.16.1 (from August 2019) which appears to have no known security issues?

Comment: It seems the package is not maintained anymore for this architecture (armhf)... there is one alternative you might consider by using docker. https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current latest, 1.13.1, which supports ALPN and HTTP 2.0 by using the Ubuntu sources. *As an aside: it's best to put modifications to your apt sources in the sources dictionary rather than sources.list itself, it helps in terms of maintainability.*

Create a file for the repository

`sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list`

Run the following to add a reference to the Ubuntu repository, and debian jessie backports.

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
    # jessie-backports, from stretch-level but with no dependencies
    deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free

    # Nginx repository - use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial to get packages compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2
    deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
    deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
EOF'
```

Update your sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install/Upgrade OpenSSL

```
sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports openssl
```

Install/Upgrade Nginx:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Done.

Comment: On Raspbian Stretch, it did not change the version offered. 
```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.3-1+deb9u1~bpo8+2
  Version table:
     1.10.3-1+deb9u1 500
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
     1.10.3-1+deb9u1~bpo8+2 990
        990 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main armhf Packages
```

Comment: you need to install Nginx via
apt-get -t jessie-backports install nginx

Answer (score 1):

I followed @Joe's suggestion, it did not work in Raspbian Stretch

`nginx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.3-1+deb9u1
  Version table:
     1.10.3-1+deb9u1 500
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
     1.10.3-1+deb9u1~bpo8+2 100
        100 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main armhf Packages`

Then I changed packages to refer to stretch backport and debian package instead of Ubuntu,

```
# stretch-backports
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free

# Nginx pre built packages
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx
```

The new one gives me

`nginx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.13.3-1~bpo9+1
  Version table:
     1.13.3-1~bpo9+1 990
        990 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main armhf Packages
     1.10.3-1+deb9u1 500
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages`

Comment: Thanks for this. After changing the package URLs like you recommended, I had to install nginx like this: `apt-get install -t stretch-backports nginx -y --allow-unauthenticated`.